# how to change the icon of the shortcut of accde in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Everyone I created a DB and after that, I compile it ACCDE and I use Inno setup for making installer of ACCDE file but I have a problem I want to change the Icon of the shortcut which is created by inno setup on the Desktop. Any idea how to perform this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put down {commondesktop} as Name in the Icons section, if you want to make a shortcut on the Desktop Window. That's all.

Assume the name of your ACCDE is "example.accde".
See below.

```
#define MyAppName "Example"
#define MyAppFullVersion "0.1.0"
#define MyAccdeFileName "example.accde"

[Setup]
AppId={{2D9CC75F-E3DA-4E86-A659-03301DDE1C33}}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#'V'}{#MyAppFullVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}

[Files]
Source: "{#MyAccdeFileName}"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAccdeFileName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IconFilename` parameter of your `[Icons]` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=IconFilename):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\My DB"; Filename: "{app}\db.accde"; IconFilename: "{app}\myicon.ico"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and do you have any idea to change the icon of ACCDE I mean the main Icon of main accde

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change icons of ACCDE file type (of all icons of that file type)?